# Same Jqueries need to be rendered in most of the templates in Meteor, should I follow DRY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, highcharts, meteor-blaze

Below are the repeated codes I have used inside template.name.rendered in meteor, and I have more libraries like highcharts.js yet to include, I don't feel it DRY, should I follow DRY ? or any other solution for this situation ?

```
Template.foo.rendered = function() {
 Session.setDefault('highcharts', false);
 if (Session.get('highcharts') === false){
   if (Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), 'admin') === true && highcharts === false) {
      $.getScript('/javascripts/highcharts.min.js', function(){ 
      Session.set('highcharts', true);
        );
      }
    }
  }
};

Template.fooBar.rendered = function() {
 Session.setDefault('highcharts', false);
  if (Session.get('highcharts') === false) {
    if(Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), 'admin') === true && highcharts === false){
      $.getScript('/javascripts/highcharts.min.js', function(){ 
      Session.set('highcharts', true);
        );
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to go about this is to have both of those templates be included inside of a Layout, and have this code inside of that layout (assuming you are using iron-router).

Comment: I tried that approach, rendering on each template only seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply provide a named function to elminate the duplication. That could have your code looking like:

```
var innerFunction = function() {
 Session.setDefault('highcharts', false);
 if (Session.get('highcharts') === false){
   if (Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), 'admin') === true && highcharts === false) {
      $.getScript('/javascripts/highcharts.min.js', function(){ 
      Session.set('highcharts', true);
        );
      }
    }
  }
};
Template.foo.rendered = innerFunction;
Template.fooBar.rendered = innerFunction;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new file where you can move your duplicate lines of code and make it as function. You can do this.

function.js

```
  this.highChart = function(_default){
    if (!_default) { // equal to if(_default === false)
     if(Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), 'admin') === true && highcharts === false){
      $.getScript('/javascripts/highcharts.min.js', function(){ 
      Session.set('highcharts', true);
        );
      }
    }
}
```

}

And from your rendered function, you can just do like this:

```
Template.foo.rendered = function() {
   Session.setDefault('highcharts', false);
   highChart(Session.get('highcharts'));
};

Template.fooBar.rendered = function() {
  Session.setDefault('highcharts', false);
  highChart(Session.get('highcharts'));
};
```